# Merging 2 dataframes in python based on a column

Tags: python, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1['Date','Ref #','Queue', 'Text']
df2['Ref #','Queue'].
```

df1 contains multiple occurences of same Ref no along with other variables.

```
Date       Ref# Queue Text
1/11/2018   1    AA    abc
1/11/2018   1    AA    xyz
1/11/2018   2    BA    xyz
```

df2 contains unique ref# with queue.

```
  Ref# Queue 
   1    AA 
   2    BA 
   3    BA
```

I need to extract Date & Text from df1 and add it to df2 based on ref#.

```
Date       Ref# Queue Text
1/11/2018   1    AA    abc
1/11/2018   2    BA    xyz
```

I tried following but it didn't work.

`result <- dataset_final[['Reference #','Queue']].merge(df1[['Text','Date Created']],on='Reference #',type='Left')`

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Comment: You should include your desired output. It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Please see edited post @jpp.

Comment: Thank you @Bsquare for your inputs.

Comment: What is your complete source code so far? Did you try something like on [this guide](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/)?

Comment: Did the guide help you?